# Заполнение объекта водой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы вода в этом примере https://jsfiddle.net/wsygj8q4/2/
 обтекала бутылку, а не накладывалась на нее?

```css
.body {
  width: 149px;
  height: 706px;
  background-image: url("http://s010.radikal.ru/i311/1711/9c/d679c55a8026.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 122px 298px;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.body .tank {
  width: 94px;
  height: 182px;
  background-image: url("http://s04.radikal.ru/i177/1711/a6/141640ec7964.png");
  background-size: 103px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 23px;
}

#water {
  background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/xTiTnrfZfRPJ520yly/giphy.gif");
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity:0.3;
  width: 95px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#tank:hover #water {
  height: 350px;
  background-position: top left;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:left">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="tank">
      <div id="water" style="height:50%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас сам танк не прозрачный, если изображение спрятать за него, то не будет видно воды. Вам нужно сделать 2 пнг. 1ый пнг на фон, потом вода, потом пнг с белым не прозрачным фоном вокруг бутылки, и с прозрачным где должна быть вода

Comment: `png` бутылки должно быть полупрозрачной, чтобы под ней было видно воду, остальное `z-index`, если я правильно задачу понял

Comment: @DaemonHK, с opacity хорошо получилось, а z-index как применить?

Comment: Так у вас же обычный бекграунд имедж стоит. Разве что маской детайте... Ну или если допустимо, чтобы вода не была в голубых ободах - подгоняйте по размер бутыли

Comment: а если эту бутылку нарисовать в svg и вашу анимацию поставить фоном ?

Comment: в вашем случае это реализовать не возможно .. так как у вас просто изображения и tank и вода

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Можно использовать свойство mask-image - работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме IE. Для этого создадим div-обертку, и наложим на него маску бутылки (для этого сделал b/w бутылку в png):

```css
.body {
  width: 149px;
  height: 706px;
  background-image: url("http://s010.radikal.ru/i311/1711/9c/d679c55a8026.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 122px 298px;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.body .tank {
  width: 103px;
  height: 182px;
  background-image: url("http://s04.radikal.ru/i177/1711/a6/141640ec7964.png");
  background-size: 103px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 23px 18px;
}

.water-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("http://s012.radikal.ru/i319/1711/0a/d4a760a32e93.png");
  mask-image: url("http://s012.radikal.ru/i319/1711/0a/d4a760a32e93.png");
}

#water {
  background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/xTiTnrfZfRPJ520yly/giphy.gif");
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity:0.3;
  width: 103px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#tank:hover #water {
  height: 350px;
  background-position: top left;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:left">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="tank">
    <div class="water-wrapper">
      <div id="water" style="height:50%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```